# Calendar timezone is behaving strangely

Tags: java, windows-7, timezone

I recently downloaded and installed Java 1.6.0_43 (32-bit version).  I'm running on Windows 7 with a 64-bit processor.  I find the following line:

```
System.out.println(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone().getDisplayName());
```

prints "Venezuela Time"... as I am in Chicago, this is rather surprising!

I've searched but can't find anyone else having this problem.  Does anyone have any idea what is going on here?  Even a tip about how I might try to debug this issue would be useful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are in Chicago, but what timezone is your computer set to?

Comment: The computer is set for Central time.

Comment: Are you sure your computer is set to `(UTC-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)`?  It sounds like it is sent to `(UTC-04:30) Caracas`.

Comment: I checked Control Panel --> Date & Time and see "(UTC-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)" listed under Time Zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into Control Panel and check your Date and Time settings. This answer is just troubleshooting, more could fill this space...

Comment: On a hunch from the advice on this page, I tried setting the time zone to Eastern, then setting it back to Central.  Voila, success.  I wish I had a better explanation for what I was seeing, but alas, this is the best I can do.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I am almost a 100% sure it is not a java issue.

Here you can see how to set the timezone in Windows 7:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/set-the-clock

On the other hand, in Windows 7 you can use **TZUtil /L** in a command prompt to see all time zone names and identify yours.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff715394(WS.10).aspx

After that, you can modify the value for **TimeZoneName** variable contained in the **custom.ini** file